# Exchange server wildcard certificate error

Tags: ssl, outlook, certificate, exchange-server, wildcard

We have a local Exchange server that we are testing out. We also have a wildcard certificate and wanted to use that certificate for Exchange. We got the certificate installed correctly, but we get an error notice when Outlook connects to Exchange.

The error is:

"exchange.office.domain.com
...
The name on the security certificate is invalid or does not match the name of the site"

When I "View Certificate...", I see the correct certificate, issued to "*.domain.com"

I am not sure if the problem is that the * does not work for exchange.office, that is how we have the network setup however.

Does anyone know how we can get Exchange to work with the wildcard certificate (we do not want to buy another certificate for testing), or if the problem is the multi-host in the FQDN, how we can get around that?

Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if Exchange has their own rules, but for HTTPS a certificate for `*.example.com` does not match `foo.subdomain.example.com`. A wildcard is only valid for a single label and only for the leftmost label. See also https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52478/why-does-firefox-not-trust-this-us-government-ssl-certificate/52479#52479

> how we can get around that?

Your only options are to either change the hostname (or provide an alias) to match the certificate or to change the certificate to match the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard SSL Certificate can only secure first level domain name.

- If you have purchased wildcard SSL certificate for '**domain.com**', using wildcard you can secure '*.domain.com' sub-domains. (First Level)
- If you have purchased wildcard SSL certificate for "**.domain.com**", using wildcard you can secure '*.*.domain.com' sub-domains. (Second Level).

As you wants to secure "**exchange.office.domain.com**" , it is a second level domain name option. So to secure it you need to buy Wildcard SSL certificate for "**office.domain.com**".